How to disable a combination of Ubuntu keybinds (Alt + [anything) when gaming
I'm aware of how to edit keybinds and custom shortcuts within the settings, and I have read Ubuntu's documentation about keybinds; however, what I'm trying to avoid is making a bunch of keybind changes, which I'm very familiar with, just so I'm not triggering Ubuntu shortcuts when I'm playing games.
I found this tool for windows, and someone who developed a Linux version:

Windows: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/WinActive.htm

Linux: https://github.com/phil294/AHK_X11
I'm thinking about testing checking for the active window matching X game then suspending all the Alt commands for the operating system. However, I did see someone state that game developers are familiar with AHK and look for it in their anti-cheat software, so... there's that.
Does anyone have a better approach or advice?

Is this when using steam?

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Although it could be, right now it's when playing World of Warcraft, which is through the Battle.net application via Lutris, and it doesn't have a "disable windows key functionality" setting, as far as I've found.

Interesting. I didn’t know of Lutris- I’ll have a closer look next time I fire up my Ubuntu box
